# Using STL algorithm to find all matches in a set

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, find

I have a set containing Song objects.
I want to search for all occurrences of a Songs that have a particular title.
I am required to use a STL algorithm.

The problem is when it finds the first occurrence it stops searching.

I am trying to fix it by using a while loop and changing where to start the search from but I am having trouble getting it to work.

**Original Function**

```
set<Song> SongLibrary::SearchSong(string title)
{
    set<Song> foundSongs;

    find_if(begin(m_songs), end(m_songs),[&](Song const& p)

        {
            if (p.getTitle() == title)
            {
                foundSongs.insert(p);
            }
            return p.getTitle() == title; });

    return foundSongs;
}
```

**This is my attempt at modifying it to use a while loop**

```
while (startSearch != m_songs.end)
{
    find_if(startSearch, end(m_songs), [&](Song const& p) // wont take start search as a parameter
    {
        if (p.getTitle() == title)
        {
            startSearch == m_songs.Position(); // this Line is wrong
            foundSongs.insert(p);
        }
        return p.getTitle() == title; });
}
```

**Attempt at using Copy_if**

```
copy_if(m_songs.begin(), m_songs.end(), foundSongs, [&](Song const& s), s.getTitle() == title);
```

Comment: Instead of `std::find_if` it seems more like you could use [`std::copy_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy), since that's what you're really doing.

Comment: @tobi303 It was a different question, I have been working on it since then to return a set

Comment: `std::find_if` stops searching when it finds a match. This is by design, it returns an iterator to the first element found in a container. You are simply using the wrong algorithm. It seems to me you are confusing `std::find_if` with [`std::for_each`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each). Consider using `std::copy_if` instead as mentioned in another comment.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I am currently trying to use copy_if, But how do i get the title of each song?                                                 copy_if(m_songs.begin(), m_songs.end(), foundSongs, Song.getTitle() == title);

Comment: Can you use a std::multiset and a comparator based on the title?

Comment: oh sorry didnt notice that

Comment: Couldn't you use [std::set_union](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_union) for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a case like this, you normally want to use `std::copy_if`:

```
set<Song> SongLibrary::SearchSong(string title)
{
    set<Song> foundSongs;

    std::copy_if(begin(m_songs), end(m_songs), 
        std::inserter(foundSongs, end(foundSongs)),
        [&](Song const &s) { return s.getTitle() == title; });

}
```

[Unrelated aside: I used the same signature as in the question, but it's at least worth considering passing the parameter by const reference rather than by value.]

If you were storing the songs in a sequence container (e.g., `vector` or `deque`), you could probably use `std::partition` instead:

```
auto pos = std::partition(begin(m_songs), end(m_songs), 
    [&](Song const &s) { return s.getTitle() == title; });
```

In this case, `[m_songs.begin(), pos)` are the range of songs that match the request, and `[pos, m_songs.end())` are those that didn't match.

Also note that a `set` stores items in sorted order. Therefore, if `getTitle()` is used as the key (or at least the primary key) when sorting the members of the set, you may be able to do things a bit more efficiently--you can use the set's `equal_range` member to find all the songs with the same title. This will give you iterators to the beginning and end of the range with logarithmic complexity. You'll then copy that range (with linear complexity), so if the range you care about is only a small percentage of the entire set, this may give a substantial speed improvement.

Comment: Thank you, That solved my problem and gave me some really helpful information. :)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately in functions like `copy_if` one can't use `std::back_inserter` to the containers which doesn't have `push_back` function and `std::set` doesn't have that, However you can achieve the same by copying it into the vector.

```
// Suppose i want to copy all occurrences of 1
set<int> v{1, 2, 1, 4,1, 6, 1, 1, 9, 10};
vector<int> newSet;
std::copy_if(v.begin(),v.end(),std::back_inserter(newSet),[](int val) {  return val == 1;});
```

But why are you using `set`. From the code, it doesn't looks like that `Songs` instance should be stored in sorted order.

Unless and until you need to store `Songs` in sorted order of Unique Elements you can use 'vector` to be able to achieve what you're trying to do by doing this

```
vector<int> v{1, 2, 1, 4,1, 6, 1, 1, 9, 10};
vector<int> newSet;
std::copy_if(v.begin(),v.end(),std::back_inserter(newSet),[](int val) { return val == 1;});
```